# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: Bulk renaming script

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

This is one of my first python scripts designed to go into a directory and rename all the files of a certain extension to the same thing. For instance, go into a music directory and change the name of all the album artwork files to something like folder.jpg so that they're easily recognized and displayed by music playing software like foobar2000.

I'm currently getting the error in the title. I've tried:

```
os.chmod(pathname, 0777)
```

and

```
os.chmod(pathname, stat.S_IWOTH)
```

to allow other entities to edit the directory I'm looking at, but the error remains. I'm not too familiar with Windows's permissions system or with Python so this is mystifying me. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
#Changes file names in every subdirectory of the target directory

import os
import sys
import shutil

#Get target path
pathname = raw_input('Enter path for music directory (ex. C:\\Music): ')
try:
        os.chdir(pathname)
except:
        print('Failed. Invalid directory?')
        sys.exit()
#Get variables for renaming
fn = raw_input('Enter desired file name for all converted files: ')
ft = raw_input('Enter the file extension you want the program to look for (ex. .jpg): ')
outname = fn + ft

#Create path tree
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk (pathname):
        #Search tree for files with defined extention
        for name in files:
            if name.lower().endswith(ft):
                #Rename the files
                src = os.path.join(path, name)
                print (src)
                dst = os.path.join(path, outname)
                print dst
                shutil.move(src, dst)
print('Complete')
```

A second more benign issue is that when I use a print statement to check on what files are being edited, it seems that before the first .jpg is attempted, the program processes and renamed a file called d:\test\folder.jpg which doesn't exist. This seems to succeed and the program fails in the last loop the second time through, when an existing file is processed. The program runs like this:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter path for music directory (ex. C:\Music): d:\test
Enter desired file name for all converted files: folder
Enter the file extension you want the program to look for (ex. .jpg): .jpg
d:\test\folder.jpg
d:\test\folder.jpg
d:\test\Anathema\Alternative 4\AA.jpg
d:\test\Anathema\Alternative 4\folder.jpg

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Programming\Python scripts\Actually useful\bulk_filename_changer.py", line 29, in <module>
    shutil.move(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 301, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'd:\\test\\Anathema\\Alternative 4\\folder.jpg'
>>>
```

The glitch seems to be benign because it doesn't cause an error, but it might be related to an error I have in the code that leads to the IOError I get when the first "real" file is processed. Beats me...

Comment: I set up a folder and tried this script out on text files and Jpegs and it went into each folder and renamed any and all files of the specified name and extension. The only way I got an error was if the file was deemed **read only**. Are any of your file properties set to read only?

Comment: No, I double and triple checked that under folder properties.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that d: is not a CD drive or something not writable. If so then have you checked the properties of your files? Are any of them read only? There would also need to be more than one of the file type in the folder to cause this, I believe.

[image: Check Read only Properties of files]

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I've disabled "read only" on that folder many times to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, your code worked for me as far as I understand how you want it to work, and I only got that error when there were more than one file of the type and at least one of them was read only. Did you check the files properties, not just the folders?

Comment: I see this. All the files and subdirectories have Read-Only unchecked but this is what you see when you get the properties of D:\test: http://imgur.com/LrRN6Ft

Comment: @SciurusDoomus So if you click that until it is empty, then everything will work? I mean it really should be 'd:\\test\\Anathema\\Alternative 4\\folder.jpg' that is read only according to your error message, I would have thought.

Comment: Already tried. That and I tried using os.chmod(pathname 0777) to force it which didn't work.

Comment: @SciurusDoomus The only other thing I could think of is that a process is using that file, `d:\test\Anathema\Alternative 4\AA.jpg`, holding it open, and not letting you rename it. Good luck.